# TCPDF generates corrupt file when displaying 'large' image

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF (the latest version – 6.0.023) to generate PDFs. In the document's header I show a logo (either in JPEG or PNG format). It turns out that when using 'large' images (> 30KB), TCPDF generates a corrupt PDF file.

This is the code that displays the image:

```
<?php
public function Header() {
    // $this->headerLeftLogo = '@' . $image;
    // $this->logoHeight = 8;
    $type = (...some check...) ? 'JPEG' : 'PNG';
    $this->Image($this->headerLeftLogo, $this->getX(), $this->getY(), 0, $this->logoHeight, $type);
}
?>
```

After inspecting the source code of the generated PDF, and comparing a good and corrupt PDF, it seems like the corrupt PDF files just end somewhere in the middle of the document. Some (readable) information I see at the end of a good PDF is not present in the corrupt PDF.

No errors show up while generating the PDF. (All PHP errors are turned on.)

When running TCPDF's example 9 (in which a large image is displayed), no problems occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had to let TCPDF resize the image. After adding `true` for the `$resize` parameter of `Image()`, the script worked fine.

Specifically, this was the change I made:

```
<?php
// Old:
$this->Image($this->headerLeftLogo, $this->getX(), $this->getY(), 0, $this->logoHeight, $type);
// New:
$this->Image($this->headerLeftLogo, $this->getX(), $this->getY(), 0, $this->logoHeight, $type, '', '', true);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful! I had the same problem, albeit it seems to happen only on certain systems (Centos) while on others (Debian, Ubuntu) I did not have the problem. Forcing the resize however fixed it :)